# Importing only a few class from a dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

I'm developing a modular web-app where I'm using maven.
The skeleton of my application is the following:

[image]

The skeleton of my application with the share-services module

[image]

Now I want to import some classes of Service-App1 within Service-App2 but without the Service-App1 dependencies( like Module-App1, Util-App1 and the external dependencies).

Summarazing, since in the App2 I have a composite persistence unit [Composite Persistence Unit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Composite_Persistence_Units) and I want to share some business logic between applications. For example if in App1 I have a spring service like this:

```
public interface ContractService {

    void processSomethings();

}

@Service
public class ContractServiceImpl implements ContractService  {

    public void processSomethings(){
            //Manage some share entities

    }


}
```

I would want use the method

> processSomethings()

also in App1
How can I realize this?

Comment: If you need it separately you need to create a separate module (maven module) and use this.

Comment: @khmarbaise Also I thought to make a separete module (shared service), but  you can suggest how to put it in my skeleton (from who depends, inherits and of what project is sub-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a project (jar output) that contains just the classes that are shared between the two consumers. This may seem like an overhead, but it leads to clean well-organised code. If you can't do this, it is an indication that you have a confused dependency hierarchy. I do this regularly to implement web service clients and services, with a shared jar that contains the classes in common (i.e. the client should know nothing about DAO classes, but does need to know the signature of the web service operations. It also needs to have access to the POJO classes that define the data and message structure).

Also, do you need the hamcrest dependency at runtime? My experience is that it can usually have its scope set to test, so it never turns up in your compiled artifacts.

I'm not a convert to parent poms, and certainly would not consider the two-level parent pom structure you show. My objections are:

- If you update a parent pom, you then need to update all the child poms that use it, negating the advantage of centralising your dependency information.
- Putting module declarations in a parent pom seems to produce a circular reference. If you change the parent pom, it tries to compile the modules, which immediately refer back to the parent, which is not yet available in the repository as it hasen't finished building. I've seen systems where there is a "dependency parent" and a "compile all modules parent" to work around this. I do use parent poms sparingly, but only to set the compiler version and to define the versions of external dependencies like Spring and Apache commons jars.

I'd like to hear reasoned argument on this topic.

Comment: @kiviron I used a two level of parent pom why App1-Parent contains different extermal dependencies to App2-Parent (different spring version and external dependencny for example ). Instead for my main problem  I updated my question with my new structure. But now this how to import this new module in my project (external dependeny or sub-module). Can you help me by putting the skeleton of your application?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `<exclusions>` section to your maven dependency, and list the transitive dependencies you don't want to inherit.

For example, if my pom.xml has a `<dependencies>` section which looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...then when I do a `mvn dependency:tree` I get the following output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building scratch 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ scratch ---
[INFO] com.nppc.mes:scratch:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I decide that I really don't want the `hamcrest-core` dependency in my project, I can modify my pom.xml to exclude it like so:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...which gives me a `mvn dependency:tree` output of:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building scratch 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ scratch ---
[INFO] com.nppc.mes:scratch:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Exclusions works only on artifacts or in other words jar files but not on class level.

Comment: @khmarbaise The OP specifically mentioned that he wants to exclude Module-App1 and Util-App1, which are .jar files according to his diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and I certainly hope not.

One of the ideas of OO programming was encapsulation, which includes the idea of hiding the implementation details of the class you are using.  You are not supposed to know what classes it depends on, though you ARE supposed to be able to discover what libraries it uses.  But for the purpose of using the class in the library, you should not be able to just pick and choose classes out of the library that you decide you need; there would be NO guarantee that the ones you DO need would work.

Comment: Perhaps I failed to make myself understood and I updated my question